# Regex for finding multiple spaces after certain content

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get the number of all the spaces after the specific word `(<{varx}>)`. Here are my strings.

Point P is `(<{var1}>,<{var2}>)` and point Q is `(<{var3}>,<{var4}>`        ). What is the slope of line `PQ`?

It doesn’t matter that which coordinates represent point 1 and point 2, `frac{4}` but the choice must remain consistent when applying the formula. This problem let us use point `P` as point `1 x1 = %{<{var1}>|n}%`

After finding the word with spaces I need to `trim` that word and replace it with original string.

```
trimFunction(data) {
    let tags = data.match(/<{var\d+}>/gm)
    let tag = [];
    if(tags) {
        tags.map(function(item, index) {
            console.log('irem',item);
            tag = item.trim();
            data = data.replace(tags,tag);
            console.log('original data',data);
        });
    }
    return data;
}
```

I tried this but not able to get the spaces, also didn't get any luck from other questions, The spaces are not showing in question but affecting my XML so I want to remove all the spaces after that certain word.
Note: There can be different no. of spaces after **`<{var3}>`** any number in place of 3.

Comment: Sorry, either it is the question formatting or wording that make it sort of unclear. Do you want to remove whitespace chars that follow `<{var\d+}>` pattern? Then why use a loop, just use `data = data.replace(/(<{var\d+})\s+>/g, '$1')`

Comment: Your question is quite difficult to read.  You say "Here are my strings, but I don't really see anything that might be a string.  Would you mind editing your question and clearly showing what your input is, and your expected output?  Please use the quote feature to highlight them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
data = data.replace(/(<{var\d+})\s+>/g, '$1')
```

The pattern means

- `(<{var\d+})` - Group 1: `<`, `{var`, 1+ digits, `}`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `>` - a `>` char.

The `$1` only keeps the contents of Group 1 in the result.